# How to replace activity in Android library project's manifest with another

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a child project that contains an activity within its manifest that I would like to use in place of one already defined in the manifest of a library project used by that child project.  Is this possible?  I thought about using Manifest Merger but can this work if the activities are named differently?

Is it possible to specify a marker that would be used to indicate the one to replace?

If not, can the replacement be done based on category instead?

Comment: Why don't you copy that Activity to your project ?

Comment: I want to override the activity in a library with one from my child project.

Answer (score 5):

You were correct about using Manifest Merger. In your projects `AndroidManifest.xml` file add following statements.

```
<application>
...
    <activity
          android:name="TheOneToRemove"
          tools:node="remove"/>
    <activity
          android:name="TheOneYouWantToAdd"
          />
...
</application>
```

This way you will exclude activity from the library and include yours.
See [this documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Selector-examples) for details.